# Edit Basic sidebar-offcanvas from relative to static Position with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i need to make my relative offcanvas to  Static Position with the same effect of transition !!! please check my live demo and make scroll

[DEMO](http://mohammadsamy.com/KN/KN.html)

i need somthing like this [Demo](http://www.loaistudio.com/)

I tried to make the sidebar with the same height with Jquery like that :

```
$('#sidebar').height($(window).height()- 51);
```

its working but, i need to make it static with the top bar also

Answer (score 0):

set `position` attribute to `fixed` . It will help your sidebar fix at position where ever you have placed it  .

Comment: check the Demo please , i know this info :(

Comment: Check out his `main.js` . I am sure you will find waht you are asking for. But  he used lots of js and css, grid system etc. Its not a single line solution

Comment: i added this line for the height only , not for the position !!